# Android device crashes when setting FPS, while it is in range of getSupportedPreviewFpsRange

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I have an innerclass `CameraView` that extends `SurfaceView`.

Inside the `surfaceChanged()` function I use the following code to set Camera parameters:

```
Camera.Parameters camParams = mCamera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> sizes = camParams.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
// Sort the list in ascending order
Collections.sort(sizes, new Comparator<Camera.Size>() {

    public int compare(final Camera.Size a, final Camera.Size b) {
        return a.width * a.height - b.width * b.height;
    }
});

for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++) {
    if ((sizes.get(i).width >= imageWidth && sizes.get(i).height >= imageHeight) || i == sizes.size() - 1) {
        imageWidth = sizes.get(i).width;
        imageHeight = sizes.get(i).height;
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Resolution: " + imageWidth + " x " + imageHeight);
        break;
    }
}
camParams.setPreviewSize(imageWidth, imageHeight);

for(int[] arr : camParams.getSupportedPreviewFpsRange ()){
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Supported range: " + arr[0] + " - " + arr[1]);
}

camParams.setPreviewFrameRate(frameRate);
mCamera.setParameters(camParams);
```

The for loop inside this print the following range: `Supported range: 4000 - 60000`, which means that my device should support between 4 and 60 fps.

Now when I set `frameRate = 45` (which is well withing the range), my app crashes with the following exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
>               at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
>               at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1876)

This does not happen if `frameRate = 30`. Can someone explain why is my app is crashing? Can the `getSupportedPreviewFpsRange()` not be trusted?

## Edit 1

I've now also tried `camParams.setPreviewFpsRange(frameRate*1000, frameRate*1000);`, same crash result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently if you set the fps in a second, different call (So getParameters and then only set the fps and assign the params to the camera) it works. No idea why, but at least that solves this issue...

Comment: Interesting. I am working on a similar problem in an application where I'd like to manually change camera settings such as `p.setZoom(10);`,  `p.setRotation(270);`, and `p.setPreviewFpsRange(4000, 6000);`. The first two settings work fine, setPreviewFpsRange however crashes after 1 update.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you cannot force the fps value for the camera hardware (at least not with any value between 4000 and 60000.

Looking at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewFrameRate(int)), the method is deprecated since api level 9.

As they suggest, you will need to use [setPreviewFpsRange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewFpsRange(int,%20int)) in replacement with the exact range returned by **camParams.getSupportedPreviewFpsRange**.

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128271/setpreviewfpsrange-not-working-despite-values-being-within-getpreviewfpsranges) question also as reference.

Comment: Hmmm, yes I've seen this question too. The problem is I require a stable amount of FPS, and like I said just setting the FPS to 30 by force works... so any idea?

Comment: @Gooey what happens if you use setPreviewFpsRange (45000, 45000)?

Comment: That was my edit; the framerate is set to 45 there, resulting in``setPreviewFpsRange (45000, 45000)``, it crashes with the same error.