# Access denied finding property "camera.hal1.packagelist"

Tags: android, android-service, android-camera, android-camera2

While using camera in service mobile screen is getting un-touchable(locked by transparent window )
and only below error is occuring

```
Access denied finding property "camera.hal1.packagelist"
```

what will be the reason and its solution?
Please help..

Comment: why down vote,
at least give/ provide your opinion about question before downvote

Comment: Same here, have you found any solutions？

Comment: I had change whole implementation, but for this issue, I dont found any solution, still waiting for right answer

Answer (score 4):

I was working with the OpenCV tutorial code for camera app on android. I encountered the same error, and after looking at the answers I indeed missed one permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Although the app doesn't save any data externally, without this permission, the access denied error occurs. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: what is the reason for this ?

Comment: Found another helpful link which suggested to actually check App permissions in settings . In my case, permissions got revoked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889800/cannot-open-camera-an-error-occurred-while-connecting-to-camera-0

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error in my app, i was using surface view and had it weight set to zero. I changed it back to 1 and the error got resolved. Do check your xml code, it may help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the Camera 1 API on my Test device "LG V30". I found out, that this message (`Access denied finding property "camera.hal1.packagelist"`) appeared when I opened the camera like this:

```
int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
    Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
    if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
        camera = Camera.open(i);
        cameraId = i;
    }
}
```

Important is, that this only happened for the LG V30, which has 2 back cameras (`numberOfCameras=3`).

After some testing I found out, that this works for this device:

```
/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
```

The example code above will access the first, back-facing camera on a device with more than one camera. [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera) you can find a detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if you asking for the Camera permission from the user.
Just specifying the permission in manifest is not gonna work above a certain Android level.

This will solve your problem.

How to ask for permission follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).

Comment: I have asked required permissions, that is not an issue

Comment: Strange I was getting the exact same issue you described when I was using my app on Android Oreo device. As soon as I started asking permission it got resolved. Also the error logs also says the same.

Comment: may be your issue had permissions issue, but in this case, permissions are being asked, and I am not even testing on Oreo,
I am testing on One Plus3, 5 devices

Answer (score 0):

## about `Access denied finding property` like error

- **less possible** reason: lack related user permission

  - which

    - should added related config

      - `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.xxx"/>`
    - when running app, first popup window for grant related permission, user self should Accept it

      - to give/grant the permission to app
- **most possible** reason = probably:

  - cause by (previous log, you can see it logcat) the warning log:

    - `type=1400 audit(xxx): avc: denied { xxx } for name=xxx dev=xxx ino=xxx scontext=xxx tcontext=xxx tclass=xxx permissive=0`

## how to fix `avc: denied` error ?

- Simple:

  - refer offical doc [Validating SELinux  |  Android Open Source Project](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate) try use `audit2allow` and related tool to fix.
- Detailed:

  - refer my [another post's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533551/access-denied-finding-property-persist-vendor-log-tel-dbg/63259127#63259127)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was for using `Camera` in android versions higher than `API 23`, I made two implementations.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        camera = Camera.open();
        parameters = camera.getParameters();
        camera.startPreview();
    }
```

...

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
    }
```

For more information there is `Camera`, `Camera2` and `CameraX` source https://developer.android.com/training/camera/choose-camera-library